# How to configure maven to copy dependencies from central repo to local repository mirror (not local repo)

Tags: maven, copy, local, mirror, maven-central

All

Need to get maven to copy central dependencies to local filesystem repository mirror. Can't work out how to do this in maven (3.3.1).

We have:

[1] maven central, which for the UK is: "http://uk.maven.org/maven2"

[2] local remote filesystem repository mirror: "c:/mylocalRepository"

[3] local repo "c:/users/*myuser*/.m2/repository"

Version of maven is 3.3.1 (doing a migration from 2.0.10).

We need to run our system without connecting to central (behind firewalls) and also without using a repository manager (Nexus, Archiva or the like) - it's something we would like to change but cannot change our infrastructure immediately. Please don't reply just saying do this.

Therefore we need our dependencies in a local file system that maven will then be use as a mirror of central.

I can't find a way to configure maven to build this - I'm getting dependencies - jar + pom and then using

To install jars:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file
-Durl="file:///{repositoryPath}" 
-DrepositoryId="InternalRepo" 
-Dfile="{jarFile}" 
-DpomFile="{pomFile}" 
-DrepositoryLayout=default 
-DgroupId={groupId} 
-DartifactId={artifactId} 
-Dversion={version} 
-Dpackaging=jar
-s "C:/apache-maven-3.3.1/conf/settings_centralRepo.xml"
```

To install Poms:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file 
-Durl="file:///{repositoryPath}"
-DrepositoryId="InternalRepo" 
-Dfile="{pomFile}" 
-DpomFile="{pomFile}" 
-DrepositoryLayout=default 
-DgroupId={groupId} 
-DartifactId={artifactId} 
-Dversion={version} 
-Dpackaging=pom
-s "C:/apache-maven-3.3.1/conf/settings_centralRepo.xml"
```

Ideally would like a configuration that we could put in the parent pom that would trigger all dependencies to be copied over. However the documentation implies this is for build artifacts rather than dependencies. There's usually a way in maven, but it can be hard to find.

Any help much appreciated - I've currently jury-rigged a script to do this and it tedious and labour intensive.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to run a local repository manager like Nexus? Artifactory and Archiva are other options.